# Design architecture for abstract ETL process wrapping different frameworks

Tags: python, machine-learning, wrapper

I intend to develop a python based abstract ETL pipeline framework that shall be applicable to different frameworks such as Tensorflow, PySpak, Scikit, you name it. The motivation for this is, to

- 1) separate training from scoring
- 2) have a clean etl description in
- 3) be able to perform different steps from above on potentially different systems
- 4) Save and load the pipeline process framework independently, which is necessary for 1)

All of the three above offer some pipelining concept (PySpark.ml piplines, Transformers and pipelines plus fit() and transform() in Sklearn, ...), and afaict the main problem is that the abstract base class would just be a lot of wrappers to be written and a lot of maintaining to be done when objects such as Imputers change.

Another main motivation is the inclusion of metadata, which also holds for instance information about what transforms (imputation, clippings, user defined methods) are useful and should be applied to properly use a table. Having this in ONE, UNITED way would be nice.

**My question:** Have you ever done something similar, do you have ideas how to deal with the wrapping mountain or even some better approach, esp.

Thanks for suggestions!